# Application has different appearance when running through docker

Tags: user-interface, docker, graphics, themes, appearance

I'm successfully running a GUI application through docker, but when doing so, the appearance changes.

**Run docker**

```
docker run -i -t --net=host -e DISPLAY -v /tmp/.X11-unix/:/tmp/.X11-unix --env="QT_X11_NO_MITSHM=1" myimage
```

E.g. when running Firefox, the standard appearance changes to classic (ugly) when running it through docker.

Here are the original and the change appearances:

[image: Original vs Changed appearance]

In my own created app, the formatting also changes because of that.
Any suggestions how to prevent this change when running app through docker?

Comment: More than likely the container doesn't have the same X11 framework (e.g. gnome) installed, or if installed, the theme you're using on your desktop isn't available/configured inside the container.